# Android: How to use user input from an activity in a class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to make an Android application that prompts the user to enter  height and width, then a square is drawn in the middle of the screen to the dimensions the user entered. My problem is that I don't know how to get the 2 numbers that the user has entered and use them as the values for height and width in my drawGrid class. Does anyone know how this is done, my code is below.

Activity...

```
public class Grid_Input extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid__input);

    createUsersGrid();
}

private void createUsersGrid(){
    Button btnMakeGrid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMakeGrid);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText editText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    btnMakeGrid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Level_Editor.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

DrawEditor class that extends View

```
public class DrawEditor extends View {
    int screenHeight, screenWidth;
    float x, y;

    public DrawEditor(Context context) {
        super(context);
        screenHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        screenWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    }

    public void drawGrid(Canvas canvas) {

        int height = ;    //<--HOW DO I USE THE USER INPUT TO SET HEIGHT HERE?
        int width = ;
            canvas.drawLine(newX, startY, newX, stopY, green);


    }

        @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawRect(screenWidth-400,screenHeight-200,screenWidth-100,screenHeight-100,red);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to draw the square? In Grid_Input or Level_Editor?

Answer (score 1):

Pass your data to leveleditor via intent

```
private void createUsersGrid(){
    Button btnMakeGrid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMakeGrid);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText editText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    btnMakeGrid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Level_Editor.class);
            String editText2String = editText2.getText().toString();
            String editText3String = editText3.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("width", editText2String);
            intent.putExtra("height", editText3String);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

get date in leveleditor via

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("width");
getIntent().getStringExtra("height");
```

Add setter method to your DrawEditor 
and draw it :)

public class DrawEditor extends View {
        int screenHeight, screenWidth;
        float x, y;
        int height, width;

```
    public DrawEditor(Context context) {
        super(context);
        screenHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        screenWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    }

    public void setHeightAndWidth(int height, int width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void drawGrid(Canvas canvas) {

        if(height != 0 && width != 0) {
            canvas.drawLine(newX, startY, newX, stopY, green);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawRect(screenWidth - 400, screenHeight - 200, screenWidth - 100, screenHeight - 100, red);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your values from Grid_Input activity to Level_Editor like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Level_Editor.class);
intent.putExtra("width", editText2.getText());
intent.putExtra("height", editText3.getText());
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

And get the values at Level_Editor like this:

```
String ht = getIntent().getStringExtra("height");
String wt = getIntent().getStringExtra("width");
```

Create a method in DrawEditor class to accept height, weight values. Call the method to pass these value to DrawEditor.

Lets say

```
public void initValues(String height, String weight) {
        mHeight = Integer.parseInt(height);    
        mWidth = Integer.parseInt(weight);          
    }
```

Call initValues on DrawEditor class object like this

```
 DrawEditor de = new DrawEditor();
de.initValues(ht, wt);
```

Finally refer these mHeight, mWidth values where you want to use in your code.

Hope this helpful for you.

Comment: this gives me an error int ht = getIntent().getStringExtra("height");

Comment: i think its because its a string and im trying to set it as an int?

Comment: It is for just reference. Use this reference and change your logig. It will work for you.

Comment: i dont uderstand the last part calling the initValues on DrawEditor,

Comment: I think you will have object available for  DrawEditor class in Level_Editor. So call the DrawEditorObject.initValues(ht, wt); method to initiate mHeight, mWidth values.

Comment: Please accept answer if it is correct so that others can refer this in future for the same problem.